# regex.PatternSyntaxException Exception generated when replace + sign with white space in phone number

Tags: android, string

When I replace phone number + sign with white space using following code, Then exception generated

code:

```
phonenum.replaceAll("+","");
```

Exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 1:
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replaceAll` method seems to use regular expression so I would guess that it fails because `+` is not a valid regular expression, `+` must have something to repeat.

Try `phonenum.replaceAll("\\+","")` instead to escape it and match a literal "+".